# Series, Looks Simple, but I am Stuck

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I promised a friend that I could help her about math questions. Yet, I am stuck with a series question. I have written the open form of each term. And I have split the general term into multiples. I have tried many other versions of the general term. I couldn't... I need at least a pointer. Thanks.

$$a(n) = \frac2{n^2+2n}$$

What is the sum of first 9 terms of the series above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\dfrac2{n^2+2n} = \dfrac2{n(n+2)} = \dfrac1n - \dfrac1{n+2}$$
Now write the first few terms and see the cancellations happening...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

$a_{n} = \frac{2}{n^2+2n}$ ?

If so, consider rexpressing $a_{n}$ using partial fractions.